# How to assign a class to execute onClick?

Tags: java, android, class, button, onclick

fellow coders!

So I'm pretty fresh on coding, and just migrated from C# to Java!
Everythings works out the way I want:
I've coded some fancy looking circular buttons, and created the following class:

```
    package com.example.haavard.gosecure;

/**
 * Created by haavardkleven on 08.08.2016.
 */

import java.util.Random;


public class PasswordGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int length = 16; //Adjust the lenght of the generated password here
        System.out.println(generatePswd(length));
    }

    static char[] generatePswd(int len) {
        System.out.println("Your secure password is:");
        String charCaps = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String chars = "absdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String numbers = "1234567890";
        String symbols = "!@#£$%^*_=+-/.?<>)";

        String passSymbols = charCaps + chars + numbers + symbols;
        Random rnd = new Random();

        char[] password = new char[len];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            password[i] = passSymbols.charAt(rnd.nextInt(passSymbols.length()));
        }
        return password;
    }
}
```

Now, since my memroy of coding and knowledge of "Android Studio" isn't that high, I have this problem:

How to I assign my class method to a onClick listener in the MainActivity?
I want my application to run the class, and print the result to a textfield already setup on the layout page.

I know, probaly there is a topic like this, but I really can not seem to find any good answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity in the layout-XML, add `android:onClick="yourMethod"` to your button.

In the activity itself, create a method like this:

```
public void yourMethod(View view){

}
```

The onClick will now automatically access this method.

In the method, you can access your class `PasswordGenerator` and call your static method. the final code could look like this:

```
public void yourMethod(View view){
    char[] pw = PasswordGenerator.generatePswd(42);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks alot!
It really helped me out! Thank you for explaining the besics as well, got the hang of it now, hehe

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below in main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="generatePswd"
    android:text="Button1" />
```